# View pager not showing all my views

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on view pager and  loading fragments.and I am using fragment pager adapter.Problem i have 6 fragments.If i go to fourth fragment and i go to first fragment,my first fragment destroyed and restarted again.I dont want to restart the fragments again.How to stop destroying the fragments.I am using viewpager.setOffScreenLimit also.My fragments not restarting ,then problem its not calling any methods in onCreateView.How to solve this problem.I want six slides(Introslider).if i go back and next i need to get previous and next data.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code of `onCreateView()` method to `onUserVisibleHint()` method.

From [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean))

> setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)
>
> Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently
>   visible to the user.

Comment: where i have to use this method ,do u have any sample for this.

Comment: In your every fragment of view pager. It is an overrided method